# How i show list data from laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, laravel-8

How I can show list data like this one, with list for product, Unit of measure, adjustment quantity, and note.

[image]

with this code

```
$stock = StockAdjustment::with('product_adjustment')->get();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($stock as $list) {
        $row = array();
        $sku = array();
        $product_name = array();
        $available = array();
        $adjust_qty = array();
        $total = array();
        $note = array();
        $date = Carbon::parse($list->create_at);
        $row[] = $date->format('d-m-Y');
        foreach($list->product_adjustment as $product){
            $sku[] = $product->product['sku'];
            $product_name[] = $product->product['product_name'];
            $available[] = $product->available;
            $adjust_qty[] = $product->adjustment_qty;
            $total[] = $product->total;
            $note[] = $product->note;
        }
        $row[] =  $sku;
        $row[] =  $product_name;
        $row[] =  $available;
        $row[] =  $adjust_qty;
        $row[] =  $total;
        $row[] =  $note;
        $row[] = $list->user['name'];
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return DataTables::of($data)->escapeColumns([])->make(true);
```

this is what I got, I can't make list for product name, adjusment quantity, total, and note. It give a coma, not list

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to achieve this by adding some stylings

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).